# How to extract good quality frame in pixel format from live mpeg-ts stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

I use the command below to stream my ts file for my programe:

```
ffmpeg -re -i independent_frame.ts -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10002
```

Below is the code of my programe, I'm trying to extract each frame in pixel format from the stream by using FFmpeg, but I found the quality is not good as it should be of the extracted frame ( I know OpenCV can do this, But I have other reason have to use FFmpeg ). I tried to put `-qscale:v 2` in FFmpeg command, but it seems change nothing. Does anyone know how to enhance the frame quality in this case? Thanks!

```
stream = 'udp://127.0.0.1:10002'
H, W = 720, 1280

command = [ 'ffmpeg',
            '-i', stream ,
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', # brg24 for matching OpenCV
            '-qscale:v', '2', 
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            'pipe:' ]

# Execute FFmpeg as sub-process with stdout as a pipe
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)#10**8

# Load individual frames in a loop
nb_img = H*W*3

# Read decoded video frames from the PIPE until no more frames to read
num = 0
while True:
    # Read decoded video frame (in raw video format) from stdout process.
    buffer = process.stdout.read(W*H*3)

    # Break the loop if buffer length is not W*H*3 (when FFmpeg streaming ends).
    if len(buffer) != W*H*3:
        break

    img = np.frombuffer(buffer, np.uint8).reshape(H, W, 3)
    num +=1

    if num == 435:
        cv2.imwrite('435.png', img)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)  # Show the image for testing
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

process.stdout.close()
process.wait()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I think superuser looked at the code and decided it was a programming question but it's actually asking how to configure ffmpeg. Delete this and try https://video.stackexchange.com/ but leave out all the code and focus on the ffmpeg config part.

Comment: `'-qscale:v', '2'` has no effect when the output format is raw video (`'-f', 'rawvideo'`). The quality is related to the streaming part. Try to avoid re-encoding by adding `-c copy`: `ffmpeg -re -i independent_frame.ts -c copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10002`.

Comment: `rawvideo` is lossless. What's likely happened is an unexpected color shift due to the pixel format conversion. Likely need to use colorspace or zscale filter for correct conversion.